# Error when trying to use a function on an element in a tuple PYTHON

Tags: python, function, tuples, output, call

```
def square(x):
    return lambda x: x**2


object = (1,2,3)
print (object[0])
print (square(object[0]))
```

output =
1,
<function square.. at 0x03494F10>

Why did the square not work for the tuple element?

Comment: Think about what `square` is returning. Is it a number, or something else?

Comment: You declared a function that builds a function to square a given value.  You never called that built function.

Answer (score 0):

Square is returning a pointer to a function, if you want to actually execute the function, you should write:

```
print (square(object[0])())
```

Answer (score 0):

`lambda` is the syntax to create an *anonymous function*.

```py
square = lambda x: x**2
```

is equivalent to...

```py
def square(x):
    return x**2
```

The latter is preferred for clarity and is how your code ought to have looked. You aren't usually supposed to assign your lambda expressions to names like `square` - they are a convenience for those times when you're supposed to pass a function as an input to something else and want to define one in-place - but *nothing actually prevents you from doing so*.

If you check the printed output you'll see that it is in fact telling you that it's returned a function.

Comment: The latter half is right, but the OP may very well want to return a function from their function (or rather, that may have been the intent of the original author). Forming a closure over a parameter and returning the closure is pretty common. If that is the intent, returning a `lambda` directly is fine. It's "named lambdas" that PEP8 cautions against.

Comment: From context I reckoned the OP was surprised that the output wasn't simply the square of the input - agree it's possible the function came from somewhere else and the OP misunderstood its purpose.